# Do you get disadvantage attacking a creature two sizes smaller than you?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, creature-size, advantage-and-disadvantage

**Background**

I'm fairly new to D&D and I've only got the free Player and DM Basic rules from the website.

**Do you get disadvantage attacking a creature two sizes smaller than you?**

And conversely, do you get advantage attacking a creature two sizes larger?

I may be confusing this with another edition, but I thought I had read in there that you got disadvantage on the attack roll against a creature two sizes smaller. For example, a human(medium size) attacking a badger(tiny size). Or a human against a huge or larger creature.

In going through the PDFs again, I can't find it mentioned anywhere. I also searched through the site and couldn't find any questions relating to this, but I'll admit that my search-fu may be sub-par.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the PHB we have the following rules concerning a size difference of two or more:

- You cannot move through a hostile creature's space unless it is two or more sizes bigger than you. (PHB 191, Player's Basic Rules 71)
- You can drag or carry a grappled creature but your speed is halved unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you. (PHB 195)

But **no automatic advantage or disadvantage based on size.**

*NB Small creatures do attack at disadvantage when wielding heavy weapons (PHB 147, Basic Rules 46), but that is because of their size and the weapon's property, not the relative size of the opponent.*

Answer (score 3):

No, size does not affect attacks.

It's possible that the restriction that you're thinking of is that you cannot grapple or shove a creature 2 sizes larger than yourself. There are a number of other exceptions around size, but none that affect regular attacks.

The primary rules on creature size in combat are on page 71 of the Player's Basic Rules.